# JavaScript object is undefined

Tags: javascript, object, element

I need some help please with a javascript object. it goes like this:
I call this function `addFilter(element)` with a html DOM element.

The function looks like this:

```
function MyList() {
    this.arr = new Array();
    this.index = 0;
}

MyList.prototype.add = function(filter) {
    this.arr[this.index++] = filter;
    //alert(this.arr[0] + ' mylist arr');
}

function Filter(element) {
    this.setElement(element);
}

Filter.prototype.setElement = function (element) {
    this.element = element;
    this.kinorid = $(element).attr('id');
}

function addFilter(element) {
    filters.Add(new Filter(element));
}

var filters =  new MyList();
```

Now with in another  function that in my case the function creates the jquery UI Slider, and every time the slider changes i need to get the parent element of that element that was sent to `addFilter` like i said in the beginning. so then i try doing

`var value = filters.arr[0];`

but like i said it id undefined.

Can any one please help me by reviewing  the code, and tell me whats wrong.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You'll have to quote more of your code, and in particular the actual context in which you're calling `filters.arr[0]` (and for that matter, what `filters` is -- we can guess it's probably an instance created by `MyList`, but we shouldn't be guessing). The code you've quoted should be okay.

Comment: Also, please do take the time to properly format code in questions. I've fixed it for you this time, but after 18 previous questions, it's really something you should be doing automatically. Refer to the handy **How to Format** box to the right of the question text area, the **[?]** above it, and the preview below it (to check it's correct).

Comment: As TJ said, you need to show how you create an instance of MyList and how you call the various methods. Also, `this.index` is just `this.arr.length`. And are both *Add* and *AddFilter* constructors? By convention only functions designed to be called as constructors should start with a captial letter.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, thank you for formatting for me, and thanks for the tips for next time.

Comment: @ RobG. I added above how i create on instance of MyLIst , Add and AddFilter are not constructors, (i am new to js object so i might be saying wrong things.

Comment: @Ovi: No worries. You still haven't quoted the code that's referencing `filters.arr[0]`, without which no one can help you. (Regarding the `Add` and `AddFilter` methods: In JavaScript, the convention is to use functions with initial capitals only for constructor functions like `MyList` and `Filter`, and not for other functions. So `Add` and `AddFilter` would be `add` and `addFilter`. It's just a convention, but if you follow it it will make it easier for people to read your code.)

Comment: It may also help to describe what you are trying to do. Showing code that *doesn't* do what you want is not sufficient. It's not a good idea to have *addFilter* dependant on a global variable (*filters*) that may or amy not exist. Better to have a filter object passed to the function.

Comment: I edited the function see above.

Answer (score 0):

You still haven't said where or how you're using `filters.arr[0]`, without which it's very difficult to help you.

Assuming your code using it looks something like this:

```
AddFilter($("#theElement"));
display(typeof filters.arr[0]);
filters.arr[0].element.css("color", "blue");
```

It should be working; [live example](http://jsbin.com/ovuki4).

My only thought is if `AddFilter` and `filters` are not defined within the same scope. You're using `filters` within `AddFilter`, so `AddFilter` must be defined in the same scope as `filters` (or in a sub-scope). So this would be fine:

```
var filters;
function AddFilter() { ... }
```

And this

```
function AddFilter() { ... }
var filters;
```

And this

```
var filters;
$(function() {
    function AddFilter() { ... }
});
```

But not

```
function AddFilter() { ... }
$(function() {
    var filters;
    // ...
});
```

...because in that last case, `AddFilter` is defined outside the scope in which `filters` is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very convoluted, I don't understand it at all. Anyway, you are looking for (I think):

```
var value = filters.arr[0].element;
```

since you assign the element reference to `arr[this.index]`.

Incidentally, if you are passing an element, then:

```
$(this).attr('id');
```

is an awfully slow way to do:

```
this.id;
```

#### Edit

The code I used (where there was a div with id 'd0' in the DOM):

```
var filters = new MyList();
AddFilter(document.getElementById('d0'));

alert(filters.arr[0].element);
```